# evaluating value of an expression as expression in groovy

Tags: groovy

Here is the code i am trying to get working

```
    def expr = ''
    List params = []
    params << 'filter-name'
    params << 'servlet-name'
    params << 'url-pattern'

    params.each{expr = expr+ "it.'${it}'.text().trim()#"}
    expr = expr.substring(0, expr.length()-1)

    consNodes.each{
        println "data is:$"{expr}"
        println "actual : ${it.'filter-name'.text().trim()}#${it.'servlet-name'.text().trim()}#${it.'url-pattern'.text().trim()}"
}
```

in the above result comes like

```
data is:it.'filter-name'.text().trim()#it.'servlet-name'.text().trim()#it.'url-pattern'.text().trim()
actual : presenceLogoutFilter##/adfAuthentication/*
data is:it.'filter-name'.text().trim()#it.'servlet-name'.text().trim()#it.'url-pattern'.text().trim()
actual : remoteApplication##/rr/*
data is:it.'filter-name'.text().trim()#it.'servlet-name'.text().trim()#it.'url-pattern'.text().trim()
actual : ServletADFContextFilter#GetHandler#
data is:it.'filter-name'.text().trim()#it.'servlet-name'.text().trim()#it.'url-pattern'.text().trim()
actual : ServletADFContextFilter##/PresenceServlet/*
```

So, as you can see that my constructed expression is not able to evaluate further. Any advise on how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a `GString` like this: `"it.'${it}'.text().trim()#"`, but then you're converting it into a `String` when you concatenate it: `expr + "it.'${it}'.text().trim()#"`. Once you turn a `GString` into a `String` it no longer evaluates expressions. But even if you address that it won't solve your problem because `GString`s do not evaluate like you think they do. The best way to explain it is with an example:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

// What you're doing
def a = 'John'
def b = 'Hello, $a'
def c = "${a}"

assert b == 'Hello, $a'

// What the compiler is doing (ignoring the variable name changes)
def aa = 'John'
def bb = 'Hello, $a'
def cc = new GStringImpl([] as Object[], ['Hello, $a'] as String[])

assert cc == 'Hello, $a'

// What you want the compiler to do, but it will not.
def aaa = 'John'
def bbb = 'Hello, $a'
def ccc = new GStringImpl(['John'] as Object[], ['Hello, '] as String[])

assert ccc == 'Hello, John'
```

If you really want to, you can build the `GString`s manually, but that will be very difficult. And you'd end up depending on a class which is not guaranteed to remain backward-compatible between Groovy releases.

Here's what you can do instead:

```
def params = []

params << 'filter-name'
params << 'servlet-name'
params << 'url-pattern'

def evaluators = params.collect { 
    { attr, node -> node[attr]?.text()?.trim() ?: '' }.curry(it)
}

consNodes.each { node ->
    println evaluators.collect { c -> c(node) }.join('#')    
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
presenceLogoutFilter##/adfAuthentication/*
remoteApplication##/rr/*
ServletADFContextFilter#GetHandler#
ServletADFContextFilter##/PresenceServlet/*
```

Instead of a single large expression you and up with a list of closures, each responsible for evaluating a node attribute. Then, you can join the results with '#'s.

Comment: sorry deleted the wrong comment. is collect a built in closure or just any name?

Comment: `collect(Closure)` is a method added by Groovy to Java's `Object` class, (although it's more common to use it with collections). It iterates over a collection, executing the closure against each item. Then, the output of each iteration is collected and returned as a list. See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#collect(groovy.lang.Closure)