# How to convert String to GString and replace placeholder in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I want to read a String from database and replace the placeholder by converting it to a GString. Can I do this with Eval? Any other ideas?

```
String stringFromDatabase = 'Hello ${name}!'
String name = 'world'

assert 'Hello world!'== TODO
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805214/evaluating-value-of-an-expression-as-expression-in-groovy/36806883#36806883

Answer (score 18):

You can use the Template framework in Groovy, so doing this solves your problem:

```
String stringFromDatabase = 'Hello ${name}!'
String name = 'world'

def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
assert 'Hello world!'== engine.createTemplate(stringFromDatabase).make([name:name]).toString()
```

You can find the docs here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_introduction

The GString class is abstract, and the GStringImpl implementation of the abstract class works on the arrays of strings, that it gets from the parsing phase along with values.

Comment: This is awesome https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5174410931601408

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with [Eval](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html):

```
String stringFromDatabase = 'Hello ${name}!'
String name = 'world'

assert 'Hello world!' == Eval.me('name', name, '"' + stringFromDatabase + '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

This also uses the Templates as Jacob's answer, but tries to resolve binding from current variables. Useful if you don't know what value you are replacing:

```
String stringFromDatabase = 'Hello ${name}!'
// variables w/o type or def keyword end up in this.binding.variables
name = 'world'

def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
assert 'Hello world!'== engine.createTemplate(stringFromDatabase).make(this.binding.variables).toString()
```

CAVEAT: variables that can be replaced don't have type or def keyword.

Comment: So it turns out this kinda breaks everything https://stackoverflow.com/q/67273565/1015495

Answer (score -2):

You should be using double quoted String literal if you want to use place holders.

The following should work:

```
String name = 'world'
String stringFromDatabase = "Hello ${name}!" //use double quotes

assert 'Hello world!' == stringFromDatabase
```

See the [official Groovy documentation about Strings](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings) to see other ways you can make this work.

Comment: It is working. But my stringFromDatabase is created by reading an object from database which results in a String:

Comment: Pseudocode:  
    `def templateFromDatabase = Template.get(123);  
    def stringFromDatabase = templateFromDatabase.source;  
    assert stringFromDatabase instanceof String; // true  
    ... TODO`