# SimpleTemplate created with binding.variables terminates execution when converted to a String

Tags: groovy

I was trying to implement the solution found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182902/1015495), where a template string is resolved against `this.binding.variables`.

The first part of this script is a more standard Map-based solution, such as is found [in the docs](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/SimpleTemplateEngine.html) (it's mainly to demonstrate that this overall approach is functional).

However, from what I can gather, the template bound against `this.binding.variables` puts a hard stop on execution when it's converted to a string, either explicitly with a cast or `toString()` call, or implicitly (by being sent to stdout). No exception is thrown (at least, not that I can catch) and the finally block never executes, nor does any subsequent code. Interestingly, when the bound template is passed *directly* to `println`, output **is** produced. I don't know enough about the internals of `println` to hazard a guess as to what's going on there but it doesn't crash immediately (but no further code is executed).

```
text = 'i am a ${interpolated} string'
interpolated = 'runtime'

engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
template = engine.createTemplate(text)

makeWithMap = template.make([interpolated : interpolated])
// these all work fine
println(makeWithMap)
println(makeWithMap.toString())
println((String) makeWithMap)

try {
    makeWithBindingVariables = template.make(this.binding.variables)
    // any of the below lines of code will terminate execution
    // this WILL produce output, but stop executing after:
    println(makeWithBindingVariables)
    // these will NOT produce output, and will stop executing:
    println(makeWithBindingVariables.toString())
    println((String) makeWithBindingVariables)
} catch (Exception e) { // nothing is caught
    println("am dead ${e}")
} finally { // we never get here, either
    println("how did I break a finally block?")
}
// this won't be reached if any of the above are called
println("All done")
```

If I add `this.binding.variables.each { println(it) }` directly after `makeWithBindingVariables` is created, I get the following output:

```
args=[Ljava.lang.String;@366ac49b
text=i am a ${interpolated} string
interpolated=runtime
engine=groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine@6ad59d92
template=groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate@56f0cc85
makeWithMap=i am a runtime string
makeWithBindingVariables=i am a runtime string
```

If I `println(this.binding.variables)` directly:

> [args:[], text:i am a ${interpolated} string, interpolated:runtime, engine:groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine@22295ec4, template:groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine$SimpleTemplate@5adb0db3, makeWithMap:i am a runtime string, makeWithBindingVariables:i am a runtime string]

(**NB** printing `this.binding.variables` also crashes the program)

What is going on here? The fact that I've managed to craft an object that salts the earth when converted to a string doesn't really make any sense to me, so I have to assume that I'm either doing something drastically wrong or fundamentally misunderstanding something (possibly both).

This behavior can be reproduced in an online interpreter [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5097144906153984)

Comment: What is `this.binding.variables` if you print it out?

Comment: @tim_yates I added the output to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, very interesting observation. This is definitely unintuitive.

So I ran this in a debugger in IntelliJ and turns out the following are the relevant parts of the involved groovy code (under groovy 3.0.6):

```
// SimpleTemplateEngine
public Writable make(final Map map) {
    return new Writable() {
        /**
          * Write the template document with the set binding applied to the writer.
          *
          * @see groovy.lang.Writable#writeTo(java.io.Writer)
          */
        public Writer writeTo(Writer writer) {
            Binding binding;
            if (map == null)
                binding = new Binding();
            else
                binding = new Binding(map);
            Script scriptObject = InvokerHelper.createScript(script.getClass(), binding);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
            scriptObject.setProperty("out", pw);
            scriptObject.run();
            pw.flush();
            return writer;
        }

        /**
          * Convert the template and binding into a result String.
          *
          * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
          */
        public String toString() {
            Writer sw = new StringBuilderWriter();
            writeTo(sw);
            return sw.toString();
        }
    };
}
```

Where the `println(makeWithBindingVariables)` will call the `toString` method which in turn will execute the `writeTo` method.

And running this in a debugger we see that the script does indeed **not** exit where the output stopped. The plot thickens...

We do however get a clue from this:

[image: first breakpoint]

where we are stopped in a breakpoint right before the first `toString` call on the template. Now compare this to the second breakpoint:

[image: second breakpoint]

and specifically, look at the `out` variable object identity in the script binding in the watches section at the bottom right. It went from `2804` to `2813`.

In other words, the execution of the template `toString` has executed the template and in the process replaced the groovy scripts default `out` binding variable (which is `System.out`) thus rendering any further output invisible.

So the script is not exiting...it is just producing output in a place where you can no longer see it.

This can be remedied by copying the binding:

```
    def makeWithBindingVariables = template.make(this.binding.variables.clone())
```

which prevents the template from replacing the groovy script execution environment `out` variable.

Again, not intuitive and required some serious digging, but at least it explains the behavior.

As an additional detail, the groovy `println` and I'm assuming other methods do things like this:

```
  public void println(Object value) {
    Object object;
    try {
      object = this.getProperty("out");
    } catch (MissingPropertyException var4) {
      DefaultGroovyMethods.println(System.out, value);
      return;
    }
```

Note the use of `out`.

We can also reproduce this with a simpler script:

```
println "foo"
def sw = new org.apache.groovy.io.StringBuilderWriter()
def pw = new PrintWriter(sw)
out = pw
println "bar first"
System.out.println("bar again, sw contains: ${sw}")
```

which, when executed prints:

```
─➤ groovy test.groovy
foo
bar again, sw contains: bar first
```

where the first `println` after replacing `out` is not printed to std out, but we can force writing to std out using java's `System.out.println` and we can see that the replaced print writer did capture our vanished `println`.