# Groovy: Replace template in string with variable of same name

Tags: groovy

I wish to find and replace a placeholder in my string with a variable value.

the String might look like:

`"URL from config is {{ config.url }}"`

I can find and replace the value with another string, using any of the regular methods.
I can get partway to what i want using Eval, but not quite.

Given `config.url == 'www.google.com'`
I want `{{ config.url }}` to be replaced with `www.google.com`

Futhermore, if I change the string to
`"URL from config is {{ config.url2 }}"`
it should read from the appropriate var

Here's some of what I've tried

```
// Setup
def description = 'This is my {{ config.good }} description'
def config = [:]
config.good = 'brilliant'
config.bad = 'terrible'

// Verify initial inputs
println "config: $config"
println "description: $description"

// Can I match what I'm looking for? (2 ways)
try1 =  description.replaceAll(/\{\{ (.*) \}\}/, {it[1]})
try2 =  description.replaceAll(/\{\{ (.*) \}\}/, /$1/)
println "try1: $try1"
println "try2: $try2"

// Can I make it look like I expect? (2 ways)
try3 =  description.replaceAll(/\{\{ (.*) \}\}/, {"\${${it[1]}}"})
try4 = description.replaceAll(/\{\{ (.*) \}\}/, /\$\{$1\}/)
println "try3: $try3"
println "try4: $try4"

// This works, but requires that I know the var name ahead of time and pass it in as 'x'
println "tryX1: " + Eval.x(config, 'return "This is my ${x.good} description"')

// Use the String we constructed above... this fails with:
//    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: Script1
try { println "tryX2: " + Eval.x(this, "return \"$try4\"") }
catch (ex) { println "You suck 1\n" + ex }


// Suspect I need to use Eval.me, but this fails with:
//    groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: Script1
try { println Eval.me('return "This is my ${config.good} description"') }
catch (ex) { println "You suck 2\n" + ex }

//    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static groovy.util.Eval.me() is applicable for argument types: (ideaGroovyConsole, org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [ideaGroovyConsole@7ec508e6, return This is my {{ config.good }} description]
try { println Eval.me("return \"${description}\"") }
catch (ex) { println "You suck 4\n" + ex }

//    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.$() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@11b5f4e2]
try { println Eval.x(this, 'return "${description}"') }
catch (ex) { println "You suck 5\n" + ex }

// Neither does this
try { println Eval.me("return ${description}") }
catch (ex) { println "You suck 6\n" + ex }
```

Output:

```
config: [good:brilliant, bad:terrible]
description: This is my {{ config.good }} description
try1: This is my config.good description
try2: This is my config.good description
try3: This is my ${config.good} description
try4: This is my ${config.good} description
tryX1: This is my brilliant description
You suck 1
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: Script1
You suck 2
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config for class: Script1
This is my {{ config.good }} description
You suck 3
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: description for class: Script1
You suck 4
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: Unexpected input: 'is' @ line 1, column 13.
   return This is my {{ config.good }} description
               ^

1 error
```

Comment: What about `Eval.me('config', config, '... ${config.url} ...')`

Comment: @daggett Trying to avoid having to pass in the vars on the evaluatin side - just want to read the string, look for a template, use whatever's in there and get the value from the appropriate var.  If I have to pass in the config object, it will break if I use another var, say, {{ defaults.port }}

Comment: To use templating you have to pass all variables, objects that will be used in template.

Comment: @daggett - You set me off in the right direction - Got there in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious tool in the groovy toolset for this kind of problem would be a template engine.

The following code:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def text = 'URL from config is ${config.url}'
def binding = [config: [url: 'www.google.com']]

def template = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)
def result = template.make(binding).toString()

println result
```

when run, prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy 
URL from config is www.google.com

─➤
```

The template can be re-used with different bindings like this:

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def text = 'URL from config is ${config.url}'
def template = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)

def bindings = [[config: [url: 'www.google.com']],
                [config: [url: 'www.microsoft.com']]]

bindings.each { binding -> 
  println(template.make(binding))
}
```

where I have omitted the `toString` call on the template as `println` does that for you. When run, this prints:

```
─➤ groovy solution2.groovy
URL from config is www.google.com
URL from config is www.microsoft.com

─➤
```

**updated after comments**

Not entirely sure I understand the comment but I'll give it a go. If the goal is to not have to create a separate variable and pass it to the template engine, you can kind of accomplish that like this:

```
def text = 'URL from config is ${config.url}'
config = [url: 'www.google.com']

def template = new SimpleTemplateEngine().createTemplate(text)
def result = template.make(binding.variables.clone()).toString()

println result
```

This is assuming you are in a groovy script context as opposed to say a groovy class. Groovy scripts have a built in `binding` variable (of type [Binding](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-3.0.6/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html)) which stores any variables you declare in your script (like `config`).

We can use this as the binding for the template to remove the need for having to create a custom binding object and make it possible to use whatever existing variables your script happened to have defined.

As for why we do `clone` on the script binding, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273565/simpletemplate-created-with-binding-variables-terminates-execution-when-converte/67296531#67296531). Turns out not cloning the script binding when using it as the binding for templating breaks the groovy script intput/output configuration and essentially disables output alltogether making it seem like the script exited. This could perhaps be seen as a defect in groovy as it is quite unintuitive.

**alternative method**

Yet another way is using closures. The following code:

```
def config = "foo"
def template = { "URL from config is ${config}" }
println (template())
config = "bar"
println (template())
```

will print:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
URL from config is foo
URL from config is bar

─➤
```

Comment: A much nicer solution than what I hacked together - One thing, though.. You're still having to assign the config var to the binding, which is what I was trying to avoid (See my creative abuse of Eval & evaluate() below); The only thing it takes is the temaplate, and the var to bound in inferred from the template text itself.  I suppose it might be like binding to `this` ?

Comment: Answer updated with an attempt at solving the extra dimension described in the comment.

Comment: Great update, thanks for indulging. (I realise it's probably not the best way to get things done, but it became a curiousity!)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably riddled with issues, but it does the job, without needing to know the names of the vars to pass them along (assumes they exist, should probably add some checks):

```
def simpleTemplateExample = 'This is my {{ simple }} description'
def simple = 'boring'

def nestedTemplateExample = 'This is my {{ config.bad }} description'
def config = [good: 'brilliant', bad: 'terrible']

def template = nestedTemplateExample

// Extract var name and replace "{{ var }}" with "${var}" or "{{ foo.bar }}" with "${foo.bar}"
def full_varname =  template.replaceAll(/.*\{\{ (.*) \}\}.*/, /$1/)
template = template.replaceAll(/\{\{ (.*) \}\}/, /\$\{$1\}/)

// Not needed for simple vars, but necessary for vars.like.this
def varname = full_varname.split("\\.")[0]

// This does the job
println Eval.me(varname, evaluate(varname),"return \"$template\"")

// getProperty() also works instead of evaluate()
println Eval.me(varname, getProperty(varname),"return \"$template\"")
```

Outputs:

`This is my boring description`

`This is my brilliant description`

`This is my terrible description`